# laravel multiple select query

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

How can I translate multiple select like this:

```
 select p.idProcesso, p.idParceiro, p.comissao ,p.NProcesso, p.dataPedido , p.nomeCliente, 
 e.Descricao, p.dataVisita, i.nomeImovel, f.desc, p.file_certificadoProvisorio, p.adenePaga,
 (SELECT nome from users as u where u.id = p.idAgencia) as nomeAgencia,
 (SELECT nome from users as u where u.id = p.idParceiro) as nomeParceiro
 FROM processo as p
 LEFT JOIN imovel as i on i.idImovel = p.idImovel
 LEFT JOIN familia as f on f.idTipologia = p.idTipologia
 LEFT JOIN estadoscertificado as e on e.CodEstadosCertificado = p.idEstado
 ORDER BY p.NProcesso desc
```

into laravel query builder ?

Thank you

Comment: downvoted because you have shown no effort to solve this on your own. see [ask] for details.

Comment: strugee, I tried to solve with my own and the way like KyleK shows me is the same like I did. But I would like to use paginator with this query builder. I thought there was another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the RAW method...

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select p.idProcesso, p.idParceiro, p.comissao ,p.NProcesso, p.dataPedido ,         p.nomeCliente, e.Descricao, p.dataVisita, i.nomeImovel, f.desc, p.file_certificadoProvisorio, p.adenePaga, (SELECT nome from users as u where u.id = p.idAgencia) as nomeAgencia, (SELECT nome from users as u where u.id = p.idParceiro) as nomeParceiro FROM processo as p LEFT JOIN imovel as i on i.idImovel = p.idImovel LEFT JOIN familia as f on f.idTipologia = p.idTipologia LEFT JOIN estadoscertificado as e on e.CodEstadosCertificado = p.idEstado ORDER BY p.NProcesso desc'));
```

Comment: Thanks Kylek for the answer but i thought there was another way to do this because I would like to use paginate(). Like this way it doesn't work